# objective c how to change UITableViewcell's reordering control width?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

Is there a way to reorder a table view by tap-and-drag anywhere on the table row ?

Additional info: uitableview is always in editing mode and i can reorder only when draging on the reordering control.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this - http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/reordering-a-uitableviewcell-from-any-touch-point